# Policy Kit does not allow to restart a service, despite an adequate rule

Tags: systemd, polkit

As nagios user, I cannot execute systemctl. Tracking it down to pkexec, I get :

```
-sh-4.2$ pkexec systemctl reload nagios
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/systemctl' as the super user
```

However, I have a very, very lenient polkit rule (it is a NOT a production system)

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
        var verb = action.lookup("verb");
        if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart" || verb == "reload") {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
});
```

I double check it is compiled when restarting polkit.service
What is the problem ?

```
OS : RHEL7
Sytemd version 219
PolKit version : 0.112
```

Thanks,

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the combo Sytemd 219 + PolKit 0.112 does not support the "verb" statement. Added some logging to the rule shows me this :

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/01-nagios.rules:7: verb=undefined
```

Looks like a bug in Polkit 0.112.

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in Polkit; rather it is bug (or at least a limitation) in this version of Systemd. The reason being is that the 'action' is provided by the mechanism using Polkit, and in this case that is provided by SystemD.

You can cross-check this in polkit(8)

See systemd release notes (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS)

> CHANGES WITH 226:
>
> ```
>     * When systemd requests a polkit decision when managing units it
>       will now add additional fields to the request, including unit
>       name and desired operation. This enables more powerful polkit
>       policies, that make decisions depending on these parameters.
> ```

So for the likes of RHEL7, I guess that would mean futzing around the issue using sudo, whereas this does work nicely in RHEL8.

Shame, I was looking forward to using that.